# Override @Column attribute value

Tags: jpa, jooq

I have several POJOs which will have a monetary amount. My idea is to create a generic object `MonetaryAmount` (consisting of a currency and a value), which will then be used whenever I want to represent a monetary amount in one of my POJOs:

```
public class MonetaryAmount {
    private String currency;
    private BigDecimal value;
}

public class Account {

    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_NAME")
    private String name;

    private MonetaryAmount balance; // TODO set column annotation values of currency and value

}
```

Since `MonetaryAmount` will be used in several POJOs, I couldn't annotate the `currency` and `value` attributes with the `@Column` since the column name will not always be the same in all cases. Is there any way to annotate `MonetaryAmount` attributes (e.g. `balance` in the example above) to provide the column name for the `currency` and `value` attributes in a way that jOOQ understands them when mapping/unmapping a POJO similar to how Hibernate interprets the [`@AttributeOverride`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) annotation please?

Answer (score 2):

The `@Embeddable` annotation is currently (jOOQ 3.11) not supported by jOOQ's `DefaultRecordMapper` yet. The relevant feature requests are:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2360
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2530
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6518

What you can do already now, if you're *not using the JPA annotations* on your POJOs, is to use the following aliasing notation in your query:

```java
ctx.select(
        ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NAME.as("name"),
        ACCOUNT.CURRENCY.as("balance.currency"),
        ACCOUNT.VALUE.as("balance.value"))
   .from(ACCOUNT)
   .fetchInto(Account.class);
```

This feature is documented in [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html), see:

> If Field.getName() is MY_field.MY_nested_field (case-sensitive!), then this field's value will be considered a nested value MY_nested_field, which is set on a nested POJO that is passed to all of these (regardless of visibility):
>
> - Single-argument instance method MY_field(...)
> - Single-argument instance method myField(...)
> - Single-argument instance method setMY_field(...)
> - Single-argument instance method setMyField(...)
> - Non-final instance member field MY_field
> - Non-final instance member field myField

Comment: Thanks for your response Lukas. So if I understood correctly, the `DefaultRecordMapper` checks for annotations at class level not at attribute/member level i.e. if one member is using annotations, the `DefaultRecordMapper` assumes that all members are doing so, right?

Also, since I am already using JPA annotations already, is there any alternative please?

Comment: @user1135357: Yes. A target POJO type is either JPA annotated or not. Mixing the behaviours would be too surprising. There's a pending feature request to make the `@Column` annotation optional  in the presence of a `@Table` or `@Entity` annotation: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4586. There is no alternative I can think of that uses jOOQ API directly. Of course, you can always write your own `RecordMapper` or use a third party mapper, e.g. https://simpleflatmapper.org/0106-getting-started-jooq.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Hibernate : You can used `Embedded` components.

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
       @AttributeOverride(name="currency", column = @Column(name="CURRENCY") ),
       @AttributeOverride(name="value", column = @Column(name="VALUE") )
    } ) private MonetaryAmount balance;

}

@Embeddable
public class MonetaryAmount implements Serializable{
    private String currency;
    private BigDecimal value;
}
```

Though this should work, I think in your case you should try inheritance and still use same approach to override attributes in Object Oriented way.